# TinyMCE makes page with flash app scroll down (only Chrome and Safari)

Tags: javascript, css, flash, iframe, tinymce

I have a Flash application which occupies entire browser window. I have to display TinyMCE over it, using an iframe. This iframe has to look like it was part of the Flash application.

Everything works well, besides on Chrome and Safari, as soon as TinyMCE appears, The page scrolls a bit down. This makes that the Flash app goes "up" a bit and TinyMCE looks like it were starting a bit bellow than it actually should.

**Edit: Ok, I investigated a bit more and found that what is happening is that a mysterious blank space is being inserted at the bottom of the page. Without overflow:hidden (when I see the scrollbar) this space is *outside* of the document, means inspecting with Chrome developer tools is not inside html element (the space itself is not in the DOM, I can only see html element finishes before). With overflow:hidden it appears inside of body, but I guess it's because it's somehow "included" later, or something.**

Edit2: Found some information about this problem:
http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Chrome/thread?tid=6d78452432a4c4d7&hl=en

http://www.hotscripts.com/forums/javascript/53545-scripts-causing-white-space-bottom-chrome-safari.html

But still no solution...

[image]

Using

```
overflow:hidden
```

on the page doesn't improve it, it only makes that no scrollbar appear, but the flashmovie still goes "up" few pixels.

The CSS of the page:

```
html, body, #flashcontent {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

The HTML Element on the flash app, which contains the iframe with TinyMCE is this:

```
<div id="htmlel" style="position: absolute; width: 583px; height: 386px; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); padding-top: 0px; padding-right: 0px; padding-bottom: 0px; padding-left: 0px; margin-top: 0px; margin-right: 0px; margin-bottom: 0px; margin-left: 0px; border-top-width: 0px; border-right-width: 0px; border-bottom-width: 0px; border-left-width: 0px; border-style: initial; border-color: initial; border-image: initial; overflow-x: auto; overflow-y: auto; left: 854px; top: 117px; "></div>
```

Another detail: I know it's related to TinyMCE, because when I put only a div over the flash app with the same mechanism (one that is even bigger) this doesn't happen. Using FCKeditor inside the iframe also works. It happens only using TinyMCE (and only Chrome and Safari, other browsers display it well).

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you share you website link for better understanding

Comment: no sorry, it's not public at the moment

Comment: can you show any screen shot or some more code ? :)

Comment: I added the code of the div containing TinyMCE. More code would be TinyMCE itself. I'll add a screenshot, thought it would be not necessary but give me 1 minute.

Answer (score 0):

What if you used a negative margin on the flash video?

Something like `margin-bottom: -20px;`. If that doesn't work, you could try the opposite (`margin-top: -20px;`) on the TinyMCE box.

Comment: I think I tried this but it cut the bottom of the flash video (space was still there), anyways, not a good solution since not sure if the space will have always the same height, and browser dependent... Don't have this project anymore and can't test :/

Answer (score 0):

i had same problem so a added this in tinyMCE.init

```
    oninit:function () {
        setTimeout(function(){
            $('#flashcontent').scrollTop(0);
        },0);
        //dedanaxnavi 
    }
```

i did so for my div and it fixed